# Why is 70% of my harddrive full when contents only constitue 45% of storage?

Tags: hard-drive, mass-storage

My PNY pro elite 1TB SSD external hard drive has ca 450 GB in files on it, as counted in the properties window in contents, but if I delete anything, the same "780 GB used" stays the same?

there was a .trash/ file which i deleted, it no longer appears and yet the problem persists...

My question is how I can safely remove the hidden files or whatever is filling up my hard drive?

See the properties window here
[image]

OUTPUT 1: `du -d1 "/media/peterhunter/PNY 1TB SSD/"` (Removed private folders)

```
1913344 /media/peterhunter/PNY 1TB SSD/.Trash-1000
1280    /media/peterhunter/PNY 1TB SSD/System Volume Information
371456  /media/peterhunter/PNY 1TB SSD/.Spotlight-V100
244057344   /media/peterhunter/PNY 1TB SSD/.Trashes
512 /media/peterhunter/PNY 1TB SSD/.fseventsd
1228032 /media/peterhunter/PNY 1TB SSD/Apps
678153728   /media/peterhunter/PNY 1TB SSD/
```

OUTPUT 2: `sudo du -d1 "/media/peterhunter/PNY 1TB SSD/"`

```
1913344 /media/peterhunter/PNY 1TB SSD/.Trash-1000
1280    /media/peterhunter/PNY 1TB SSD/System Volume Information
371456  /media/peterhunter/PNY 1TB SSD/.Spotlight-V100
244057344   /media/peterhunter/PNY 1TB SSD/.Trashes
512 /media/peterhunter/PNY 1TB SSD/.fseventsd
1228032 /media/peterhunter/PNY 1TB SSD/Apps
678153728   /media/peterhunter/PNY 1TB SSD/
```

Comment: did you check the trash file of the hard drive

Comment: Please [edit] into your question the terminal output of `du -d1 /media/peterhunter/`(directory of harddrive)`/` and `sudo du -d1 /media/peterhunter/`(directory of harddrive)`/`

Comment: @martinthornton my harddrives name is pny 1tb ssd.. I get "no such folder or directory" when using the command 
du -d1 /media/peterhunter/PNY 1TB SSD

Comment: @preldiot , how do i check the trash file, it doesn't appear anywhere? I don't know how to show hidden files, it doesn't pop up in the right click menu

Comment: Sorry, I didn't account for spaces. Try again with `du -d1 "/media/peterhunter/PNY 1TB SSD/"` and `sudo du -d1 "/media/peterhunter/PNY 1TB SSD/"`  If that doesn't work `ls /media/peterhunter/`.

Comment: @MARTINthornton now it worked! and i copied the output into the question, seems like there is a .trash file eve nthough i deleted it. So how do I empty the trash files?...

Comment: Thank you @martinthornton - yes, back on my ubuntu labtop this is exactly how it looked and i could manually delete files permanently. problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that macOS uses a different directory, `.Trashes`, to store trashed files.  It would also seem that the Properties window didn't count `.` directories

Ubuntu only uses `.Trash`, and `.Trash-(user number)`.  Emptying the Trashcan will empty `.Trash-1000`.

You will need to manually clear `.Trashes`, if that is what you also want.  If you are *sure* there is nothing you want to keep in `.Trashes`, then you can delete it with:

```
rm -r "/media/peterhunter/PNY 1TB SSD/.Trashes/"
```

or if that complains about permissions (be careful here):

```
sudo rm -r "/media/peterhunter/PNY 1TB SSD/.Trashes/"
```